# vb.net textbox no special characters

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox

I would like to skip a part of validation and just make it so the text-box can't have anything I don't want in it.

The intention is to allow backspaces, spaces, and letters : d,r,i (upper and lower) be entered.

How can I make it so that no special characters get entered like {}, !, :;", etc.?

```
Private Sub txtParty_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtParty.KeyPress
    'allows only numbers, letter, space, and backspace
    If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) = True And e.KeyChar <> "d" And e.KeyChar <> "D" And e.KeyChar <> "r" And e.KeyChar <> "R" And e.KeyChar <> "i" And e.KeyChar <> "I" Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use regular expression with client-side validation. Is this ASP.Net Web Form?

Comment: Adding Regular Expression Validation To A TextBox from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996428.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Probably easier with a couple of If-Blocks to filter the data.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
                              Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
  If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back AndAlso e.KeyChar <> " " Then
    If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) OrElse
      Not "DRI".Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString.ToUpper) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Of course, you would still have to intercept the Ctrl-V and remove the ContextMenuStrip to prevent pasting text into the TextBox.