# How to prevent to write , and ' in form textbox VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to prevent users to write/put `'` (single quote) or `,` (comma) in my form textbox?

I already tried:

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 188 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 222 Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

but in vain it did not work.

Comment: Your question is answered in another post: [How to avoid taking special characters in textbox of a Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965122/vb-net-textbox-no-special-characters)

Comment: i did'nt understand, i just want to prevent only two special characters ( single quote (') and comma (,)

Comment: I hope I wrong, but if you want prevent user from writing "invalid" values for sql query - there are better solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vb.net textbox no special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965122/vb-net-textbox-no-special-characters)

Comment: The Stack Overflow posts linked in the first and last comments above this one take you to a post that already explains how to do exactly what you are trying to achieve, and in the same language you have asked about, please read that post to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it didn't work for you, are the wrong character codes.

The ASCII codes are like following:

- single quote `'` = **39**
- comma `,` = **44**

If you change your code to this it will work:

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 39 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 44 Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

**Note:** copy & paste of `,` and `'` will still work.

If you want to disable copy & paste for the Textbox completely, you can set the `ShortcutsEnabled`-property to `False`.

If you don't want to disable copy & paste, you can additionally check the Textbox-content in the `Validating`-Event and replace the comma and singe qoute with an empty string:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace("'", "")
End Sub
```